# Firestore orderBy Timestamp DESC

Tags: javascript, react-native, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display the data from Firestore order by timestamp descending order, I follow the documentation but it seems that I did something wrong.

This is my try:

```
const outputSnapShot = {};
        this.subscribe = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('orders')
            .where('restaurant_code', '==', this.state.restaurantCode)
            .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
            .onSnapshot((doc) => {
                doc.docs.map(function(documentSnapshot) {
                    return (outputSnapShot[documentSnapshot.id] = documentSnapshot.data());
                });
                if (this._isMounted) {
                    this.setState({ dataSource: Object.entries(outputSnapShot) });
                }
            });
```

the result from previous code is the data order by id ASC , Also I finish the INDEXING from Firebase console like so:

[image]

I hope I explained the issue clearly.
Thanks

Comment: Could you edit the question with the source data and specific results of the query that show they are in an order that you didn't expect?  We should be able to duplicate the issue using what you show in the question.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the data and the result showing all data as I expected but it ordered by id number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a help by my friend, we came with this solution and made the code work as we expected:

Going to share this:

```
this.subscribe = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('orders')
        .where('restaurant_code', '==', this.state.restaurantCode)
        .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot((docSnapshot) => {
            const dataSource = [];
            docSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                dataSource.push(doc.data());
            });
            if (this._isMounted) {
                this.setState({ dataSource });
            }
        });
```

Comment: On my case I cannot seem to make `.where` and `.orderBy` work together. Either I remove one of the two to have a result. Any idea? You may check https://github.com/apappas1129/react-native-firebase/commit/98b26eb6f0a69def9664d261fb4d59467b827198

Comment: Any resolution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: 'desc' not found ".orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')" statement. any suggestion? Dart+Firebase+Flutter. Thanks.

Comment: I was just reading firebase docs today: 
Valid: Range filter and orderBy on the same field
`citiesRef.where('population', '>', 2500000).orderBy('population');`

Comment: Finally working solution.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, in my case the following way worked for me

```
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 var db = firebase.firestore();


 var docRef = db.collection('Users').doc('001').collection('Data').orderBy("Date", "desc")
 ...
```