# How to retrieve data based on latest timestamp

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently studying how to retrieve data using Firebase specifically using Cloud Firestore. I have created a sample database like this

[image: cloudfirestore]

So the question is how we retrieve the announcements fields based on created timestamp which is `created_at` field in descending order?

I have followed this [Order and limit data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) but the syntax does not include document reference which means it only can order by document id in the collection but not by document's fields right?

Here is my current code looks like

```
final announcementList = <AnnouncementModel>[].obs;

getAnnouncements() async {
  announcementList.value = [];

  final snapshot = await firestore.collection("announcements").doc("announcements").get();
  final data = snapshot.data()!['announcements'] as List<dynamic>;    
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    announcementList.add(AnnouncementModel(
      title : data[i]['title'],
      desc : data[i]['desc'],
      logo : data[i]['logo'],
      link : data[i]['link'],
      createdAt : data[i]['created_at'],
    ));
  }  

  announcementList.refresh();
}
```

The expected output that I want is to retrieve only top 5 latest created announcements.

The code that I have tried but returns nothing.

```
test() async{
  final snapshot = await firestore.collection('announcements').orderBy('created_at', 
descending: true).limit(5).get();

  final data = snapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data());
  print('Output $data');
}

//OUTPUT
Output ()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try  orderby with desc

take refrence from the below code

```
    db.collection("devs")
   .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    /_ your magic goes here _/;
    });

 this.subscribe = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('orders')
    .where('restaurant_code', '==', this.state.restaurantCode)
    .orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
    .onSnapshot((docSnapshot) => {
        const dataSource = [];
        docSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            dataSource.push(doc.data());
        });
        if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({ dataSource });
        }
    });
```

here is link to follow might help

[Firestore orderBy Timestamp DESC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62474577/firestore-orderby-timestamp-desc)

Comment: I'm using the latest flutter version and `orderBy` only can receive 2 parameters which are `Object field & bool descending = false by default`. This is not helping.

Comment: `.orderBy('created_at', true)` then...

Comment: how firestore refer this `timestamp` inside this `orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)`? Is it refering to `collection->documents`? or `collection->documents->documents_timestamp_field`?

Comment: @casraf I have tried it, it returns empty.