# sorting by date from firestore firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with this
[image]

However, when I get the data, i have not been able to find a way to sort this. Ideally, Emma should be above Matt when I get the data.

I tried a simple JS .sort() where `a.long - b.long`, but no go there. Is there a good way to handle this? I am in charge of collection(s), I can edit the data accordingly to make it easier to get.

```
var birthdays = [];

db.collection("birthdays").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        //birthdays.push(doc.data());
        //var birthdayDivString = '<div class="col-6">'+doc.data().name+'</div><div class="col-6">sort birthdays</div>';

        const sortedMessages = Object.values(snapshot.data()).sort((a, b) => a.long - b.long)

        birthdays = sortedMessages;

        //$("#birthdayDiv").append(birthdayDivString);

    });


});
```

Comment: I recommend including the output you get from this line of your code `console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());`. Once you do that, the problem becomes independent of Firestore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Firestore data by TimeStamp in Ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224638/order-firestore-data-by-timestamp-in-ascending-order)

Comment: JavaScript version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62474577/firestore-orderby-timestamp-desc

Comment: The data in `long` are strings, not numbers.  You can't compare them by subtracting them.  And if they're formatted as month/day without zero padding, you can't reliably compare or sort them as strings either.

Comment: What are the `1`, and `2` fields inside the document, users? Do you want to only read the document and order them? Please respond using @AlexMamo